# Getting Animator from Sprite inside Prefab (Unity)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a Controller class which has a list of GameObjects which are indeed prefabs (in my code called turtlesTypePrefab).
As you can see here, the prefabs I use have sprites inside them with animations (what I'm saying is FirstTurtle has an animator, SecondTurtle as well and so on, and they are all part of my prefab called ThreeTurtles).

[image]

So now in my code I want to change the value of a boolean inside one of these animators of my prefab.

Inside of my controller I have:

```
public GameObject[] turtlesTypePrefab;
```

And then in my update method I want to do something like:

```
void Update()
{

    for (int i = 0; i < turtles.Length; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < turtles[i].Count; j++)
        {
            GameObject turtle = turtles[i][j];

            if (turtle != null)
            {
                MoveTurtle(turtle, i);
                // THIS DOESNT WORK
                anim = turtle.GetComponent<FirstTurtle>().GetComponent<Animator>();
                anim.SetBool("diving", true);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If each turtle gameobject has its own animator component what you can do is initialize the parent animator from treeturtle gameobject GetComponentInChildren().

What you want to do is to access the one of the children animator via code from the parent. Here is an example

// this script will be attached to the parent

```
anim = GetComponentInChildren<Animator>();
```

You used this line of code which the one below:

```
anim = turtle.GetComponent<FirstTurtle>().GetComponent<Animator>();
```

The problem with it, is that FirstTurtle is a child gameobject not a component. So you can't really get FirstTurtle as a component. Using GetComponent() only work if you want to use the animator the gameobject you are working on. So I'll suggest you use GetComponentinChildren.

Comment: Thank you by doing turtle.GetComponentInChildren<Animator>() I was able to get the animator from FirstTurtle. Do you know how I could get the animator for SecondTurtle and ThirdTurtle?

Comment: Update: I ended up using GetComponentsInChildren<Animator>(); and then doing a for each. I used this: https://answers.unity.com/questions/1088469/access-a-lot-of-child-animators-at-once.html